# using EF to provide data for google map api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I currently have google map api working to display my currentl location on a map under MVC3.

I would like to present a series of points on the map generated from an EF query.

I am using the google map javascript implementation.

Can this be accomplished, and is there any good soul that would provide a code sample to send me iin the correct direction.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the controller to load up a results set, and looped through them to create a html popup for each of them in javascript.

I then added them into the google.maps.Marker routine....

Answer (score 1):

Surely, your EF Query is going to return a set of coordinates. If you NOT using Ajax to get the coordinates and creating a page, then you can create a javascript array some thing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// coordinates
var locations = [];
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(@(Model.Latitude), @(Model.Longitude));
}

// Initialze your map and add the markers from the locations array
</script>
```

In this case you have all the data you need sent to your view through the models.

The other method will be to use Ajax to get the coordinates you need to display. Here, you will have a controller that will give all the coordinates in the form of JSON or XML. You will need to process it accordingly and display the markers.

If you need help in displaying multiple markers on Google maps, refer to [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)!

Comment: Sorry - added as an edit, not a comment....  Would you expand on the model information...  please include code if you can.   thx